# How to Store the Recorded Audio Files in a Folder

Tags: android

Can anyone please explain how to store the recorded Audio files in a separate folder?

I am using default recorder for recording audio files

```
Intent = new  Intent (MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION);
startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
```

and I am getting the absolute audio path:

```
absolutepath audiopath is : /mnt/sdcard/recording1225555579.3gpp
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try by specifying the path yourself.

```
private void beginrec() throws IllegalStateException, IOException{
    ditchMediaRecorder();
    recorder=new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/voice/"); //like this
    recorder.prepare();
    recorder.start();
}
```